# match any of string in list b with list a. a is a long sentences

Tags: python, regex

```
a = ['http://www.yahoo.com', 'http://www.google.net', 'gorilla', 'house.com', 'i love the net very much']
b = ['com', 'http', 'net']

result = ['http://www.yahoo.com', 'http://www.google.net', 'house.com', 'i love the net very much']
```

How can I find b in a?
match any of b in a. a is a long sentences

my regex

```
for element in a:
    m = re.match("anything match in b right?")
    if m:
        print (m.group())
```

i don't quite sure what to put inside re.match

Comment: Does the order of `result` matter?

Comment: Where is your regex?

Comment: order doesn't matter

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
a = ['http://www.yahoo.com', 'http://www.google.net', 'gorilla', 'house.com', 'i love the net very much']
b = ['com', 'http', 'net']
print list(set([i for i in a for j in b if j in i]))
```

EDIT:

For all of b in a:

```
a = ['http://www.yahoo.com', 'http://www.google.net', 'gorilla', 'house.com', 'i love the net very much http and com too']
b = ['com', 'http', 'net']

print set(a)-set([i for i in a for j in b if j not in i])
```

Comment: great solution which I didn't think of. was trying hard to use regex. anyway,just a new question related to this. what if b is a must in a?

Comment: @momokjaaaaa here `b` is a must in `a`

Comment: i mean, all of b is a must for each list in a

Answer (score 2):

Not a regex solution, but I think you can iterate over each of the strings , and you can use [`any()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#any) for the checking. Example -

```
result = []
for i in a:
    if any(x in i for x in b):
        result.append(i)
```

Example/Demo -

```
>>> a = ['http://www.yahoo.com', 'http://www.google.net', 'gorilla', 'house.com', 'i love the net very much']
>>> b = ['com', 'http', 'net']
>>>
>>> result = []
>>> for i in a:
...     if any(x in i for x in b):
...         result.append(i)
...
>>> result
['http://www.yahoo.com', 'http://www.google.net', 'house.com', 'i love the net very much']
```

---

List comprehension solution -

```
result = [i for i in a if any(x in i for x in b)]
```

Example/Demo -

```
>>> a = ['http://www.yahoo.com', 'http://www.google.net', 'gorilla', 'house.com', 'i love the net very much']
>>> b = ['com', 'http', 'net']
>>> result = [i for i in a if any(x in i for x in b)]
>>>
>>> result
['http://www.yahoo.com', 'http://www.google.net', 'house.com', 'i love the net very much']
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a nested loop, checking each of a with a find () function using each of b.

```
if b[x].find(a[y]) != -1:
```

This if statement will indicate if a[y] was found in b[x].